# Equating the spans of two sets of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following sets of vectors in $ℝ$4:

$$A =\left\{\begin{pmatrix}-5\\ 5\\ -2\\ -2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-5\\ -3\\ -3\\ -1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}5\\ 4\\ -4\\ 5\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

$$
B=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} t \\ -6 \\ 3 \\ -13\end{pmatrix},\,\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 6 \\ 6 \\ 2\end{pmatrix},\,\begin{pmatrix} -10 \\ -17 \\ 14 \\ -13\end{pmatrix}\right\}
$$
For what (integer) value of $$ does span()=span()?

My inital thought was to create a matrix with columns of the vectors, and set that equal to a column vector b (with elements b1, b2 and b3) which represents any vector that can be formed by a linear combination of these vectors. I then tried to perform G-J elimination (which I wont put on here, it took ages!) to get some sort of expression with the b's which need to be satisfied for the system to be consistent. In theory this would give me two expressions, one in b and one in b and $t$ (by eventual dividing by $t$(?)) and set them equal to obtain $t$. I tried to do that but did not obtain an integer value for $t$. What is wrong with my method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that $B_2 = -2A_2$ and $B_3 = -1A_1 -3A_3$. So now, if you choose $t$ such $B_1$ is a linear combination of $A_i$, you complete the proof.

Why is this true? If all $B_i$ can be written as linear combinations of $A_i$, and if $v\in span\{B\}$ then $v = \sum c_iB_i = \sum \hat{c}_iA_i$ and hence, $v\in span\{A\}$ and $span\{A\}\supseteq span\{B\}$. Also if $B_i$ are linear combinations of $A_i$, then $A_i$ can be written as a linear combination of $B_i$, so by the argument above if $v\in span\{A\}$ then $v\in span\{B\}$ and $span\{B\}\supseteq span\{A\}$. Therefore, $span\{A\}= span\{B\}$.

Further note: By my approach, I found that for $t=-20$, $B_1 = A_1+A_2-2A_3$. Your approach is working from the other direction and it may be harder. I just had to solve a 3-by-3 linear system to find $(x,y,z)=(1,1,-2)$ and computed $-5x-5y+5z$ to find $t$.

Comment: one thing i don't quite get: "Also if  are linear combinations of , then  can be written as a linear combination of ". How is this true?

Comment: Eg. if i had a vector, $b_1$, and $b_1$ = $2a_1$ + $3a_2$, how can i write $a_1$ in terms of $b_1$?

Comment: I guess I should have used proper terminology and said that there is a change of bases operator between these two bases. Related part from wikipedia is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Change_of_basis

You need to know more than that, like $b_1 = 2a_1 + 3a_2$ and $b_2 = 2a_1 + 2a_2$ would give you $a_1 = 3b_2 - 2b_1$ and $a_2 = b_1 - b_2$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question that you asked at the end, your approach was a bit more complicated than it needed to be. The underlying idea was a good one: for the spans to be equal, every linear combination of the first three vectors must also be a linear combination of the other three. This is guaranteed if every one of the second set of vectors can be written as a linear combination of the first three. In fact, you may have done an exercise in which you have to prove something like “if $\{v,w\}$ is a basis for $V$, then so is $\{v+w,v-w\}$.”

So, build the augmented matrix $\left[A\mid B\right]$ and row-reduce it as you did. It’s convenient to rearrange the columns of $B$ so that the column with $t$ is the last one. You should end up with a $3\times3$ identity matrix in the upper-left corner (which tells you that the elements of $A$ are linearly independent) and a row of zeros ending in some expression in $t$ for the last row. For the last vector to be an element of the column space of $A$, then, this expression in $t$ must be equal to zero. Solve for $t$.

You could save yourself some work by assuming that the other two, fixed elements of $B$ are already in the span of $A$ and leave them out of the augmented matrix, but keeping them allows you to verify this.